# Getting "" value of Location in Lotus Notes Calendar

Tags: c#, calendar, location, interop-domino

I am trying to read Location of Calendar item in Lotus Notes.
When i check in Document Properties manually.I am able to view the value,
But when i read it via using Domino.dll in am getting "" value.

I am using:

```
String Location  = ((object[])CalendarDoc.GetItemValue("Location"))[0] as String;
```

Also tried :

```
String tmpLocation  = ((object[])CalendarDoc.GetItemValue("tmpLocation"))[0] as String;
```

is there any other way to get 'Location' value ? **using Domino.dll in C#.**

Thanx

Comment: Are you getting "" or null? There's a big difference between the two.

Comment: i am getting "" value.Made changes in Post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a wild guess... I'm wondering if it's the `as string` that's causing your issues. I think it depends on the object type being returned by GetItemValue. I'm guessing at runtime it will try to cast your object to a string which might not be what you want. You might just want the text that the object represents (assuming that the ToString gives that).

```
string location = GetLocationFromDocument();

private string GetLocationFromDocument()
{
    object[] values = CalendarDoc.GetItemValue("Location");
    if( values != null && values.Length > 0 && values[0] != null )
    {
        return values[0].ToString();
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Sorry, I don't have the required assemblies to test this. If this doesn't work I can delete my answer because I don't wan't bad information floating around.